# Как исключить поле из запроса

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Для запроса использую `aggregate`, куда передаю:

```js
[{
    $match: {
      id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'blogs',
      as: 'blog',
      pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,
          name: 1,
          articles: 1
        },
      }, {
        $match: {
          articles: {
            $in: [id]
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

Где `articles` - массив, длина которого неопределенная. Я указываю `articles` в `$project`, чтобы потом воспользоваться им в `$match`. Проблема в том, что в итоге вместе с документом мне возвращается `articles`, а это лишняя нагрузка на сервер. Как можно не возвращать поле, полученное в `$project`?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields

Comment: Возникает ошибка `Cannot do exclusion on field articles in inclusion projection`

Comment: можете попробовать просто убрать `articles: 1`

Comment: @entithat, я пытался, в итоге blog равен пустому массиву, видимо ему необходимо поле в $project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге мне помог банальный `$unset`:

```js
[{
    $match: {
      id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'blogs',
      as: 'blog',
      pipeline: [{
        $project: {
          id: 1,
          name: 1,
          articles: 1
        },
      }, {
        $match: {
          articles: {
            $in: [id]
          }
        }
      }, {
        $unset: 'articles'
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

Возможно, есть более правильное решение.